# How to define localhost IP as 10.0.2.2?

Tags: networking, localhost, virtualbox-networking

On my Ubuntu PC, I need to use `10.0.2.2` instead of `127.0.0.1` to be able to let Android emulator to connect to web server running on `localhost`. So wondering how can I define the new IP?

I edited /etc/hosts and added

```
10.0.2.2    localhost
10.0.2.2    subdomain.localhost
```

Instead and restarted the hosts using `/etc/init.d/hostname.sh`. But ifconfig still does not show the new ip. How can I fix this?

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to change /etc/hosts or machine hostname. These are just for name resolution. You need to bring up a loopback interface with this ip. So we will bring a copy of loopback (lo:1) with this ip:

```
$ sudo ifconfig lo:1 10.0.2.2 up
```

Then you can use ifconfig to see if its up. It will appear like:

```
lo:1      Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:10.0.2.2  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
```

You can use ssh to this ip.

To make this permanent you can add it to /etc/rc.local .